# jqGrid: baselinkurl open in new tab

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid (via JSON data from mysql table) to display a column of links to other html pages. How can I get the `baselinkurl` to open in a new tab of the browser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter

you can use a `showlink` and set the `target` attribute to be `"_blank"`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks for your answer. It worked!